# Create a strongly typed object from json array

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I have a an array that I populate that I would in turn like to place in a strongly-typed object.  I have this code that has been populated with json data and I would like to populate my Setting object with this data.  How can I do that?

JSON response:

Got response as:

```
[
   {
      "CatalogID":2377,
      "Category":"Frozen",
      "Facings":true,
      "ID":13,
      "LastUpdateDateTime":"\/Date(1348681365520-0700)\/",
      "Quantity":true
   },
   {
      "CatalogID":2377,
      "Category":"Fruit",
      "Facings":true,
      "ID":10,
      "LastUpdateDateTime":"\/Date(1348692069843-0700)\/",
      "Quantity":false
   },
   {
      "CatalogID":2377,
      "Category":"Salads",
      "Facings":true,
      "ID":12,
      "LastUpdateDateTime":"\/Date(1348681354807-0700)\/",
      "Quantity":true
   },
   {
      "CatalogID":2377,
      "Category":"Vegetables",
      "Facings":true,
      "ID":11,
      "LastUpdateDateTime":"\/Date(1348681334523-0700)\/",
      "Quantity":true
   }
]
```

Objective-C

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSError *error = nil;
// Get the JSON data from the website

id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSStringEncoding responseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
if ([response textEncodingName]) {
    CFStringEncoding cfStringEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)[response textEncodingName]);
    if (cfStringEncoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
        responseEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfStringEncoding);
    }
}

if(receivedData)
{
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:responseEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Got response as %@", dataString);

}

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    for (NSArray *item in result) {
        NSArray *items = [item valueForKey:@"ID"];

        [_settings addObject:items];

        // Try to populate Setting object
        Setting *setting = (Setting *)[_settings objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"Setting: %@", setting);
    }
}
else {
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

    for(NSDictionary *item in jsonDictionary)
        NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
}

NSLog(@"Finished");
}
```

Setting.h

```
@interface Setting : NSObject {

NSString *_settingsID;
NSString *_catalogID;
NSString *_category;
NSString *_facings;
NSString *_quantity;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *settingsID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *catalogID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *facings;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *quanity;

- (Setting *)initWithName:(NSString *)settingsID desc:(NSString *)category;

@end
```

Setting.m

```
@implementation Setting

@synthesize settingsID = _settingsID;
@synthesize catalogID = _catalogID;
@synthesize category = _category;
@synthesize facings = _facings;
@synthesize quanity = _quantity;

- (Setting *)initWithName:(NSString *)settingsID desc:(NSString *)category CategoryID:(NSString *)catalogID Facings:(NSString *)facings Quantity:(NSString *)quantity {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    self.settingsID = settingsID;
    self.catalogID = catalogID;
    self.category = category;
    self.facings = facings;
    self.quanity = quantity;
}

return self;

}

@end
```

Comment: I'm just not sure HOW to populate it.  I know noobie question but I'm pretty new to iOS programming.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can help you with that, but it would be useful to see what result actually is. So, if you could, after the line "if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])", log result and edit your post to show that.

Comment: @rdelmar, thanks for the help!  Ok, so good news is that my JSON response above is exactly what I found in the log window when I added this line of code: NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result); just below if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) { ...  So all I need to learn how to do is take that result and populate my Setting class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong in the code you posted. I will run through them and show you how to do it correctly, but I would highly suggest that you study the docs for NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSString to familiarize yourself with the methods available to you in those classes -- you really can't even begin to write decent code without knowing those classes well.

1) I don't really know what you're trying to do with the string encoding stuff and the code after if(receivedData). There's no need to convert your JSON into a string, the JSONObjectWithData: method converts your data to an array (more precisely, an array of dictionaries), and that's what you need to work with.

2) In your for-in loop, item should be typed as an NSDictionary, not an array. Each item in the array is the whole dictionary between the {} in your JSON that you posted.

3) All the code you have in the for-in loop is wrong -- I can't tell what you're trying to do with that. What you need to do is get the values for the various keys in your dictionary, alloc init an instance of Setting, and pass the values in that extended init method.

4) Your setting object  just keeps the values for one of the dictionaries in your JSON data, so you need to create another array to hold one setting object for each dictionary in your response (I called it settingsArray in my example below).

5) Your init method in the Setting class is different in the .h and .m, they should both look like the .m version, except that the pieces of the name after each colon should be lower case not capitalized.

So, here is the code that I think will work. Since I don't have access to your JSON, I can't test it, so try it out and get back to me with the results.

So, in the class where you are doing your download, you should have a property, settingsArray, and the following code in the connectionDidFinishLoading method:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    self.settingsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSError *error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        for (NSDictionary *item in result) {
            NSString *settingsID = [item objectForKey:@"ID"];
            NSString *category = [item objectForKey:@"Category"];
            NSString *categoryID = [item objectForKey:@"CatalogID"];
            NSString *facings = [item objectForKey:@"Facings"];
            NSString *quantity = [item objectForKey:@"Quantity"];

            Setting *setting = [[Setting alloc] initWithName:settingsID desc:category categoryID:categoryID facings:facings quantity:quantity];
            [self.settingsArray addObject:setting];
        }

    }
}
```

The init method in Setting should look like this:

```
- (Setting *)initWithName:(NSString *)settingsID desc:(NSString *)category categoryID:(NSString *)catalogID facings:(NSString *)facings quantity:(NSString *)quantity {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        self.settingsID = settingsID;
        self.catalogID = catalogID;
        self.category = category;
        self.facings = facings;
        self.quanity = quantity;
    }

    return self;

}
```

After Edit: If you want to find the value of one of the properties of a setting based on the value of another property, you can do it like this:

```
    for (Setting *aSetting in _settingsArray) {
        if ([aSetting.category isEqualToString:@"Frozen"]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",aSetting.facings);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for!  I have a couple of other questions.  Reference the JSON at the top of the post.  Notice the Category "Fruit" has a value of "true" for Facings. Say I want to get that specific value from all the data now stored in NSDictionary.  How best should I do this?  Follow up question pertains to CoreData and I'll ask that after we sort this question out.  Thanks!

Comment: All of the dictionaries have true for Facings, so I'm not sure what you're asking. Also, not sure what you're talking about with NSDictionary -- your data is now stored in an NSArray of Setting objects. Please be more specific, and I'll try to answer.

Comment: Ok, so the Settings array has categories: Frozen, Fruit, Salad and Vegetables.  Each of these categories has a setting for Facings that can either be true or false.  If I am specifically looking for the setting "Frozen" and I want to know the value stored in that Setting for Facings, which in the example above is true, how do I get that?  I thought something like   if ([self.settings valueForKey:@"Category"] == @"Frozen") {
        
       NSString *valueForFrozen = [self.settings valueForKey:@"Facings"];
    
        NSLog(@"Value For Frozen: %@", valueForFrozen);
    }

Comment: I realized after my last post I am dealing with an object.  This should work but despite seeing "Frozen" printed to the console window the if... statement is never executed.  Not sure why.  for (Setting *item in self.settings) {
    
        NSLog(@"Setting: %@", item.category);
        
        if (item.category == @"Frozen") {
            
            NSString *valueForFrozen = item.facings;
            NSLog(@"Value For Frozen: %@", valueForFrozen);
        }
    }

Comment: I am used to C# where a string comparison is done with "=="  Anyways, I removed one of the equal signs and now the if statement falls through for each object in the Settings object.  I guess I need to cast the item.category to a string and do a comparison that way?

Comment: The reason your if statement didn't work is because calling valueForKey on an array gives you an array of all the values in the array for the key "category" (or the property category in this case). So, if you log that, you'll get an array (Frozen,Fruit,Salads,Vegetables).

Comment: Yes, I realized the names were different after I did exactly that.